# Problems with Angular's NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

When testing a component that has sub-components you have a few options:

1. Import the module that sets up the component and sub-components. Problem is you instantiate the real sub-components and their dependencies.
2. Mock sub-components. This can be tedious depending on how many sub-components it has.
3. Use `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` and ignore sub-components.

Given that most of the time you only care about the current component, why isn't `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` given more attention in the testing tutorials, blog posts, etc.?

I know it's flagged as experimental but I'm not bothered by that since

1. it's shipped with the rest of Angular, and
2. the whole Angular stack is pretty much experimental given its history and the upcoming release cycle.

So are there problems with `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`? Or is it just happenstance it's not promoted more?

Comment: Because it hides *any* errors. What if you've misspelled the name of an `@Input` to a child component? You don't get to find out about that until E2E/integration testing.

Comment: I am trying to learn more about this feature as well as being stead fast in TDD for my Angular project. @jonrsharpe, are there any other draw backs for using NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA?

Comment: I switched to using NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA because test setup becomes very tedious when you have nested components.  We have a tool-window that wraps each one of our components, it's made testing a pain.  Switching to NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA has allowed us to test the code in the components with less pain.  One issue that I've seen is now our Karma tests in Chrome show the template as each test runs.  I'm not sure if this is because I should be using a null loader with the html in webpack or what... other than that NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA has been great.

Comment: @jonesharpe, the doc just says, "Defines a schema that will allow any property on any element." - not that it hides any errors. However, it hasn't been working consistently for me lately. I still have to add a bunch of stuff to the testing module. A real/official "shallow rendering" strategy would be a boon, as large testing modules make test setup horrible and test execution pretty slow.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @jonsharpe's assessment in that, you hide *any* template errors when you use NO_ERROR_SCHEMA, you will likely mask schema errors.

The alternative of importing the module with `TestBed` causes dependency-tree-hell.

There is a third alternative [shallow-render](https://github.com/getsaf/shallow-render) that will mock your dependency tree automatically so you get type-safety, template safety and dependency-tree resolution with a single line of test setup.

Full-disclosure, I am the author of shallow-render.

Comment: Hi getsaf, I've just started using shallow-render for a simple 'should create' type testcase for a component with a RouterLink, to avoid using the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA for the reasons described in this question. I have looked at the examples in shallow-render and there doesn't appear to one which shows how to write a simple 'should create' test case. I've tried and it doesn't fix the original routerLink error. I have posted a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51198288/how-to-write-angular-jasmine-simple-should-create-test-case-using-shallow-rend. It would be great if you could answer.