# How to write Angular Jasmine simple 'should create' test case using shallow-render instead of using NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a few angular (v6) components whose template contains RouterLink reference. These components have the default generated test case entitled 'should create', which breaks with the error:

> Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
>   ("12">

I can fix this using NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, for example:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ NotFoundComponent ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

But the problem with using this method is that it is a bit too brutal and hides all errors with the template (as I discovered reading this question: [Problems with Angular's NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681372/problems-with-angulars-no-errors-schema))

This question contains various solutions, 1 of which requires the use of a testing helper library called *shallow-render*.

I need to find out how to write the equivalent 'should create' test case using shallow-render instead of NO_ERROR_SCHEMA. The examples documented do not cover this scenario, so I have just tried to experiment using the other examples as appropriate. Here is my code:

COMPONENT:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'apclib-lock',
  templateUrl: './lock.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lock.component.css']
})
export class LockComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

COMPONENT SPEC:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { LockComponent } from './lock.component';
import { Shallow } from 'shallow-render';
import { AuthenticationModule } from '../authentication.module';

describe('LockComponent', () => {
  let component: LockComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LockComponent>;
  let shallow: Shallow<LockComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LockComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LockComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    shallow = new Shallow<LockComponent>(LockComponent, AuthenticationModule);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<section id="wrapper">
  <div class="login-register" style="background-image:url(../assets/images/background/login-register.jpg);">
    <div class="login-box card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginform" action="index.html">

          <div class="form-group text-center">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light" [routerLink]="['/dashboard/dashboard1']">Log In</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

ERROR:

> Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.13.5) LockComponent should create FAILED
>     Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
>   ("12">
>                   ][routerLink]="['/dashboard/dashboard1']">Log In
>                 
>                   "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/LockComponent.html@21:95

I am trying to do things the right way, and brutally hiding template errors using NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA does not seem the right thing to do, so I just need to find out how to get rid of that error for a simple creational test case using shallow-render.

PS: in https://github.com/getsaf/shallow-render/wiki/Examples it would have been nice to see an example entitled 'component with RouterLink' as this is a common error experienced by other devs and is the main reason for me trying to switch to shallow-render.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're attempting to use a combination of Shallow and TestBed. Shallow is a **replacement** for TestBed. The good news is that this makes tests much easier to write.

```js
import { Shallow } from 'shallow-render';
import { LockComponent } from './lock.component';
import { AuthenticationModule } from '../authentication.module';

describe('LockComponent', () => {
  let shallow: Shallow<LockComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    shallow = new Shallow<LockComponent>(LockComponent, AuthenticationModule);
  });

  it('should create', async () => {
    const {instance} = await shallow.render();

    expect(instance).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Side note: I'm not a big fan of Angular's "should create" default test because they don't actually exercise the component or verify any of it's behavior. I definitely recommend testing component behavior instead of simple creation tests.

If you're interested in testing the behavior of the link, the `RouterModule` can be a little weird and you *may* want/need to use Angular's [`RouterTestingModule`](https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule). If you go that route, I have an example spec on the official [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/shallow-render?file=examples%2Fcomponent-with-routing.spec.ts) that you can reference. I just updated it to use the `RouterLinkDirective` after reading this question.

Comment: Hi getsaf, thanks very much for answering my request. I have tried your solution and unfortunately, it doesn't solve this problem, I still get the same error. I reread the Shallow documentation and I have come to the conclusion it is not designed for the problem I'm having. I do like the Shallow project and will definitely be using it in the next stage of my testing. For the simple creation test, I'll stick to using NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, but for more detailed tests, I'll just create a new fixture and use Shallow. This is unless you can think of a reason why it doesn't fix my issue. Cheers again ;)

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue in StackBlitz, I'm sure I can resolve the issue. If you'd like, post the issue on the GitHub project with your StackBlitz and I'll get it taken care of. I know other devs are using shallow-render with the Angular Router.